# Xcode assistant editor doesn't show the "auto" option

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm new to iOS development, I've just learned that assistant editor can help you to link the code and UI.

But after I add a new Swift file, I found that the auto option is gone, and creating property/function by dragging the line from storyboard doesn't work anymore.

I'm using Xcode 10.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "auto" option... but what I think you might be looking for is Counterparts, which is there.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong it sounds like you just added a swift class and you were expecting to see the UI to connect the elements... please let me know if I'm wrong.

Regarding to use the assistant editor for that, first you would need to set the class for your ViewController in the storyboard (you can do that in the identity inspector), from there if you select your view controller in the storyboard and use the assistant editor it should display the Auto option, or if not you could even select manual and choose your file..

Hope this helps ;)